# Cannot set slick carousel to column grid 12 bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I got problem when I want to set my carousel to `col-xs-12`, actually every column 12 in bootstrap not set properly into slick carousel.

If I set it into `col-xs-6` it work just fine but I got 2 grid in one row. I need more space for my carousel. am I missing something ?

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6  col-md-6 col-lg-3">
    <h3 class="mb-10">User Type</h3>
    <div class="slider responsive">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="statusbox mb-0">
            <h2>Independet Agent</h2>
            <div class="statusbox-content">
              <strong>497</strong>
              <span>Updated 27/04/2015</span>
            </div>
            <!-- /.statusbox-content -->
            <div class="statusbox-actions">
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i></a>
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i></a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.statusbox-actions -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.statusbox -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.row -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="statusbox mb-0">
            <h2>Company Agent</h2>
            <div class="statusbox-content">
              <strong>1.319</strong>
              <span>Updated 27/04/2015</span>
            </div>
            <!-- /.statusbox-content -->
            <div class="statusbox-actions">
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i></a>
              <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i></a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.statusbox-actions -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.statusbox -->
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.row -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.slider-->
  </div>
  <!-- /.col-* -->
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6  col-md-6 col-lg-3">
    <h3 class="mb-10">User Membership</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="statusbox">
          <h2>Balance</h2>
          <div class="statusbox-content">
            <strong>$25,000</strong>
            <span>Updated 27/04/2015</span>
          </div>
          <!-- /.statusbox-content -->
          <div class="statusbox-actions">
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-share-alt"></i></a>
          </div>
          <!-- /.statusbox-actions -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.statusbox -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.col-* -->
</div>
<!-- /.row -->
</div>
```

this one for script slick

```
<script>
$('.responsive').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: false,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still trying to wrap my mind around your question. Here are a couple of suggestions I have to (hopefully) get you where you need to go:

1. Remove the first "col-md-12" wrapping everything.
2. Change your two columns from `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6  col-md-6 col-lg-3">` to `<div class="col-md-12">`

Is this the direction you're looking to go? What are you trying to do?

Comment: still not working . before i set slider with slick it just work fine. and the problem in small screen i have 2 grid instead of 1.